# Python library to convert jpgs to multipage tiffs

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

Is there a python library to convert jpgs to multipage tiffs? The best I could find is FreeImagePy but the documentation is really bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using the FreeImagePy libary.

```
import FreeImagePy as FIPY
F = FIPY.Image()
F.new(multiBitmap = "multipage.tiff")
F.appendPage("test1.jpg")
F.appendPage("test2.jpg")
F.deletePage(0)
F.close()
```

The output file is a multipage tiff file.

**EDIT**: I am having a problem with unusually large file sizes. Does anyone know how to compress the resulting multipage tiff file when the file is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)( This  [Tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm) contains good explanation ). Can use it as

```
import Image
im = Image.open('test.jpg')
im.save('test.tiff')  # or 'test.tif'
```

Comment: Hi, I can convert one jpg to one tiff using this method. I am trying to convert multiple jps to one single multi page tiff.